# glGenFramebuffersOES vs glGenFramebuffers?

Tags: iphone, graphics, opengl-es

I am starting out with OpenGL ES. The example code that I am reading has a lot of functions whose names end in `OES`.  What does the `OES` suffix mean?  The non-OES counterparts have [man pages](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/glGenFramebuffers.xml) but I cannot find any documentation on the *OES functions.  Would it be okay to use the non-OES man pages as a reference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `OES`-suffixed functions exist because framebuffer objects are supported via the [`OES_framebuffer_object`](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_framebuffer_object.txt) extension on OpenGL ES 1.1, but are part of the core specification in OpenGL ES 2.0 (and therefore don’t need an extension suffix).

The man pages for the non-suffixed OpenGL ES 2.0 functions should map pretty closely to the `OES`-suffixed versions, as the rules for `OES_framebuffer_object` also apply to framebuffer objects in OpenGL ES 2.0.